# ASPx Display data in textbox from SQL source

Tags: asp.net, sql, data-binding

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="textdata" runat="server"
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TextConnectionString %>" 
SelectCommand="SELECT SUM(pkNot) FROM [Not]">
    <SelectParameters>
          <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="notTotal" Name="pkNot" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
 </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And the textbox is:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="notTotal"></asp:TextBox>
```

How can I get that value to show up in the textbox?  It's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something alike this :

```
DataView beh = (DataView)SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);

TextBox1.Text = beh[0][0].ToString();
```

A other way might be :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind ('activitydate') %>'></asp:TextBox>
```

In the code behind. I wrote this in c# as you did not point out what you are using.

Comment: And where do I write the select statement?  Or at the least the field name that I pulled from the data source?

Comment: SqlDataSource1 is the name of the datasource i used in the example so i guess for you that would be textdata

Comment: I know that part, but I mean the field...the actual value I am getting from the data source. Or should I make a new datasource that only has one select statement and one value(field)?

Comment: You mean in which event? well that would depent on when you want to have the textbox filled with text. Honestly im not sure when the sqldatasource object is made but you could try load event.

Comment: I am getting this error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataView' to type 'System.String'.

Comment: How it is now (I edited it) it will put the first row into the textbox.

Comment: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: What about the new thing(s) i added?

Comment: That's not working either...gives a server tag not well formed error.

Comment: Do you know how to assign the value from my select query to a variable in the code behind(c#)

Comment: The first line of code in my answer puts the select output into a DataView called beh

Comment: The first [0] gives the table so that means the first table in DataView the second [0] means the first row. So the first row of the first table of DataView if you still catch my drift. Btw you are using C#?